# Update ListView is not working

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview that contains items. When I search using AutoCompleteTextView, the new items are added to the listview, but when I click onItemClick, it gets the old position. Can I get the position on the new listview?

```
public interface MyClickListener {
    public void click(SanPham sanPham);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, null);
    sanPhams = new ArrayList<SanPham>();
    SanPham sanPham0 = new SanPham("Coca Cola", "Giá: 165.000/thùng",
            R.drawable.flag_coca, 1,
            "Bảo hành: 12 tháng. \r\n Nguồn gốc: Chính hãng. \r\n Hãng sản xuất:" +
                    "Coca Cola. \r\n Dung Tích(ml)/Lon: 330. \r\n Xuất xứ: Việt Nam");
    SanPham sanPham1 = new SanPham("Pepsi", "Giá: 165.000/thùng",
            R.drawable.flag_pepsi, 1,
            "Bảo hành: 12 tháng. \r\n Nguồn gốc: Chính hãng. \r\n Hãng sản xuất:" +
                    "pepsi. \r\n Dung Tích(ml)/Lon: 330. \r\n Xuất xứ: Việt Nam");
    SanPham sanPham2 = new SanPham("suafami", "Giá: 165.000/thùng",
            R.drawable.flag_suafami, 2,
            "Bảo hành: 12 tháng. \r\n Nguồn gốc: Chính hãng. \r\n Hãng sản xuất:" +
                    "suafami. \r\n Dung Tích(ml)/Lon: 330. \r\n Xuất xứ: Việt Nam");
    SanPham sanPham3 = new SanPham("7up", "Giá: 165.000/thùng",
            R.drawable.flag_7up, 1,
            "Bảo hành: 12 tháng. \r\n Nguồn gốc: Chính hãng. \r\n Hãng sản xuất:" +
                    "7up. \r\n Dung Tích(ml)/Lon: 330. \r\n Xuất xứ: Việt Nam");
    SanPham sanPham4 = new SanPham("number1", "Giá: 165.000/thùng",
            R.drawable.flag_number1, 1,
            "Bảo hành: 12 tháng. \r\n Nguồn gốc: Chính hãng. \r\n Hãng sản xuất:" +
                    "number1. \r\n Dung Tích(ml)/Lon: 330. \r\n Xuất xứ: Việt Nam");
    SanPham sanPham5 = new SanPham("nuocepdau", "Giá: 165.000/thùng",
            R.drawable.flag_nuocepdau, 2,
            "Bảo hành: 12 tháng. \r\n Nguồn gốc: Chính hãng. \r\n Hãng sản xuất:" +
                    "nuocepdau. \r\n Dung Tích(ml)/Lon: 330. \r\n Xuất xứ: Việt Nam");
    SanPham sanPham6 = new SanPham("sting", "Giá: 165.000/thùng",
            R.drawable.flag_sting, 1,
            "Bảo hành: 12 tháng. \r\n Nguồn gốc: Chính hãng. \r\n Hãng sản xuất:" +
                    "sting. \r\n Dung Tích(ml)/Lon: 330. \r\n Xuất xứ: Việt Nam");
    SanPham sanPham7 = new SanPham("traxanh0do", "Giá: 165.000/thùng",
            R.drawable.flag_traxanh0do, 1,
            "Bảo hành: 12 tháng. \r\n Nguồn gốc: Chính hãng. \r\n Hãng sản xuất:" +
                    "traxanh0do. \r\n Dung Tích(ml)/Lon: 330. \r\n Xuất xứ: Việt Nam");

    sanPhams.add(sanPham0);
    sanPhams.add(sanPham1);
    sanPhams.add(sanPham2);
    sanPhams.add(sanPham3);
    sanPhams.add(sanPham4);
    sanPhams.add(sanPham5);
    sanPhams.add(sanPham6);
    sanPhams.add(sanPham7);

    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapterListView =new AdapterListView(getActivity(), sanPhams);
    listView.setAdapter(adapterListView);

    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.AutoCompleteTextView1);
    String[] data = new String[]{"Coca Cola", "Pepsi", "suafami", "7up", "number1", "nuocepdau", "sting", "traxanh0do"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, data);
    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(aa);
    autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ArrayList<SanPham> rs = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < sanPhams.size(); i++) {
                if (sanPhams.get(i).getName() == (((TextView) view).getText())) {
                    rs.add(sanPhams.get(i));
                }
            }

            listView.setAdapter(new AdapterListView(getActivity(), rs));

        }
    });
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterSpiner = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[]{"Tất cả",
            "Nước Có Ga", "Nước Không Có Ga"});
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.Spiner1);
    spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapterSpiner);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ArrayList<SanPham> rs = new ArrayList<>();
            if (position == 0)
                rs = sanPhams;
            else {
                for (int i = 0; i < sanPhams.size(); i++) {
                    if (sanPhams.get(i).getType() == position) {
                        rs.add(sanPhams.get(i));

                    }
                }
            }
            listView.setAdapter(new AdapterListView(getActivity(), rs));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (textView == null) {
                clickListener = (MyClickListener) getActivity();
                clickListener.click(sanPhams.get(position));
            } else {
                textView.setText(sanPhams.get(position).getDescription() + "");
            }
        }
    });

    return view;

}
```

Comment: From what i understood you create a new `AdapterListView` each time you use the `AutoCompleteTextView` is that right?

Answer (score 0):

### Ok first

you're comparing the two *Strings* here `if (sanPhams.get(i).getName() == (((TextView) view).getText()))` in the wrong way, you should change that to `if (sanPhams.get(i).getName().equals((TextView) view).getText())` because thats the way you compare *Strings* in **Java**.

---

### Secondly

I'd prefer that you change the `Dataset`(content) of your `AdapterListView` instead of building a new one all together, you can keep a *reference* to your `AdapterListView` and then repopulate it with your new data.

---

Here is how you can achieve this:

```
    //Define your adapter variable
private AdapterListView myAdapterListView = null;
...
//Your Adapter initialization 
listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
adapterListView =new AdapterListView(getActivity(), sanPhams);
listView.setAdapter(adapterListView);
...
```

Now depending on your `AdapterListView` implementation, i guess you have some sort of an `ArrayList` in it that you add your data to in your constructor as in here `new AdapterListView(getActivity(), rs)` so you can make a method in your `AdapterListView` called populate, that will add a new `ArrayList` to your existing adapter.

```
//Add this method in your adapter
public void populate(ArrayList newData){
  //your adapter arrayList
  this.YOUR_ADAPTER_ARRAYLSIT = newData;
  //this will refresh your adapter with the new data
  this.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}
```

Then you just call 
`//Repopulate your adapter
    this.adapterListView.populate(rs)`

instead of this

`listView.setAdapter(new AdapterListView(getActivity(), rs));`